# How can I get an element's serialised HTML with PHP's DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

This is my example script:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Capture this text 1
    </div>
    <div class="date">
    May 2010
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="text">
    Capture this text 2
    </div>
    <div class="date">
    June 2010
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);


$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    print_r($tag->nodeValue."\n");
}
```

This will out put:

```
Capture this text 1 May 2010
Capture this text 2 June 2010
```

But I need it output:

```
<div class="text">
Capture this text 2
</div>
<div class="date">
June 2010
</div>
```

Or atleast be able to do something like this in my foreach loop:

```
$text = $tag->query('//div[@class="text"]')->nodeValue;
$date = $tag->query('//div[@class="date"]')->nodeValue;
```

Comment: This question is not about XPath expression but about specific DOM implementation methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, `nodeValue` will give you the node's value. You want what's commonly called `outerHTML`

```
echo $dom->saveXml($tag);
```

will output what you are looking for in an X(HT)ML compliant way.

---

As of PHP 5.3.6 you can also pass a node to `saveHtml`, [which wasnt possible previously:](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/?view=revision&revision=307561)

```
echo $dom->saveHtml($tag);
```

The latter will obey HTML4 syntax. Thanks to [Artefacto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127724/artefacto) for that.

Comment: Combine this one with a smidgin of JapanPro's answer as to `innerHTML`, and we could have `$result = '';foreach($tag->childNodes as $tag) $result.=$dom->saveXML($tag);` with the original XPath.

Answer (score -1):

**try this**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$tags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $innerHTML = '';

    $children = $tag->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
        $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));       
        $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
    }

    var_dump(trim($innerHTML));
}
```

-Pascal MARTIN

Comment: why voted down , without testing code. leave some feedback as well while voting down.

Comment: Why is it attributed to Pascal Martin? Did you get the code from one of his answers?

Comment: @Pascal I think copying and pasting other user's answers should be discouraged here.

Comment: @alex seems to greatly based on a portion of the answer I gave there : stackoverflow.com/q/2574625/138475 *(I've had to delete/repost my comment to edit it a bit)*