# php DOMDocument How to convert node value to string

Tags: php, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get an element's serialised HTML with PHP's DOMDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805207/how-can-i-get-an-elements-serialised-html-with-phps-domdocument)
>   [PHP + DOMDocument: outerHTML for element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404941/php-domdocument-outerhtml-for-element)

I am trying to extract all img tags from a string. I am using:

```
$domimg = new DOMDocument();
@$domimg->loadHTML($body);
$images_all = $domimg->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images_all as $image) {
  // do something
}
```

I want to put the src= values or even the complete img tags into an array or string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`saveXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) or [`saveHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) on each node to add it to an array:

```
$img_links = array();
$domimg = new DOMDocument();
$domimg->loadHTML($body);
$images_all = $domimg->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($images_all as $image) {
  // Append the XML or HTML of each to an array
  $img_links[] = $domimg->saveXML($image);
}

print_r($img_links);
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael. That was what I needed. I had tried saveXML but I was using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a DOM parser like [simplexml_load_string](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_simplexml_load_string.asp). Take a look at a similar answer I posted here:
[Needle in haystack with array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888211/needle-in-haystack-with-array-in-php/8888308#8888308)