# String Replace Alphabet Ignoring HTML Tags and Elements

Tags: php, html, replace

This code almost does exactly what I want it to. The only issue is that it also replaces HTML tags and the elements. I want to get this code to ignore those HTML tags and the elements, and only replace the letters that aren't within the <...> of the tags.

Currently, it replaces every letter UPPER and LOWER with another letter. And it also prevents the already replaced letters from being replaced again. This is splendid. If I could remove the tags and leave it as plain text, I would, but it's not the desired result.

This needs to work for simple or complex strings. This is merely a simple version of what this is being done for.

```
Tags that could be included <p><br><strong><b><em><i><u><strike><s>

$foo = '
<p>
The <i>foobar</i> walks down the street.
<br />
<br />
<b style="font-size: 10px;">Foo!</b>
<br />
<br />
<strike>Foobar.</strike>
</p>
<p>
The <i>foobar</i> walks down the street.
<br />
<br />
<b style="font-size: 10px;">Foo!</b>
<br />
<br />
<strike>Foobar.</strike>
</p>
';

$replaces = array(
'A' => 'Q',
'B' => 'F',
'C' => 'J',
'D' => 'T',
'E' => 'C',
'F' => 'W',
'G' => 'N',
'H' => 'Y',
'I' => 'L',
'J' => 'H',
'K' => 'S',
'L' => 'V',
'M' => 'Z',
'N' => 'X',
'O' => 'U',
'P' => 'R',
'Q' => 'M',
'R' => 'P',
'S' => 'O',
'T' => 'K',
'U' => 'I',
'V' => 'G',
'W' => 'A',
'X' => 'B',
'Y' => 'D',
'Z' => 'E',
'a' => 'f',
'b' => 'o',
'c' => 't',
'd' => 'k',
'e' => 'i',
'f' => 'd',
'g' => 'u',
'h' => 'r',
'i' => 'p',
'j' => 'x',
'k' => 'z',
'l' => 'q',
'm' => 's',
'n' => 'v',
'o' => 'w',
'p' => 'y',
'q' => 'n',
'r' => 'l',
's' => 'm',
't' => 'j',
'u' => 'a',
'v' => 'g',
'w' => 'e',
'x' => 'b',
'y' => 'c',
'z' => 'h',
);

for( $i=0,$l=strlen($foo_replace);$i<$l;$i++ ){
    if( isset($replaces[$foo_replace[$i]]) ){
        $foo_replace[$i] = $replaces[$foo_replace[$i]];
    }
}
```

I've been Googling how to replace and ignore html tags, but none of the results provided me with something solid, nor exemplifying. The only thing that SEEMED to be the right answer was HTML DOM Parser... however, I can't find any decent examples for this particular issue. Therefore, it wasn't as useful as could be. If anyone could provide me with an explanation or example that could solve this problem, that would be great.

***EDIT***

Using the answer given, I tried to figure out what it all meant. I wasn't given a link to what parser was being used, so I had to Google around to find it. Using that code as is removed all the HTML and also changed smart tags into strange characters... not what I wanted. So I kept looking for ways to do this using the PHP DOM class, and I still can't figure it out. I don't see how to put the HTML tags back in place after making the changes I need to do.

This is what I ended up with in trying to do so...

```
function encodeMe($str , $replaces){
    for( $i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++ ){
        if(isset($replaces[$str[$i]]) ){
        $str[$i] = $replaces[$str[$i]];
    }
}
return $str;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($chapter_replace);
$nodes = $dom->childNodes;
foreach($nodes as $node) {

for($i=0,$l=strlen($node);$i<$l;$i++){
    if(isset($replaces[$node[$i]])){
        $node[$i] = $replaces[$node[$i]];
    }
}

}
$chapter_replace = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: you should parse the html and replace all innerText.

Comment: Do you have to do this server side? or can it be done on the client?  Cause javascript/ jquery could do this in a pinch.  But if not, then PHP's DOMDocument class is where you should start

Comment: This needs to be done with PHP because it has to work even when JavaScript is disabled or not available. The content is saved to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started...

```
  $str = 'The red hen walks down the street. <b style="font-size: 10px;">Bang!</b> The end.';

  $DOM = new DOMDocument;
  $DOM->loadHTML($str);

  // The encoding functin
  function encodeMe($str , $replaces){
    for( $i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++ ){
        if( isset($replaces[$str[$i]]) ){
         $str[$i] = $replaces[$str[$i]];
        }
     }
     return $str;
   }

   // Loop through the DOM, and build an encoded string
   // Here you can figure out a way to also attach the html tag to the front
   // To retain the tags uncoded.  But I didn't take the time to do that.
   // This should be enough to get you started though
       $newString="";
       foreach ($DOM->childNodes as $node)
        {
          $newString.=encodeMe($node->nodeValue, $replaces);

          // Pseudocode of how you might do it...
          // $newString.= attach front tag. encodeMe($node->nodeValue, $replaces). attach back tag;
        };

  echo $newString;
```

It will be something along these lines, but not quite.  You'll have to definitely play around abit...but this is just to get you started

**EDIT**

Heres a hackish way to do it.  Without DOMDocument....But it works.

```
      $str = '<span class="test">The red hen walks down the street.</span> <span class="second">Bang!</span> The end.';
      $html=array();
      //Explode your html string, by the < tag
      $firstEx = explode("<",$str);

      $i=0;
      // Loop through that array, and explode the > tag, encode the text portion
      // and store the pair in the $html array
      foreach($firstEx as $t){
         $i++;
         $tmp = explode(">",$t);
         $html[$i]['tag'] = $tmp[0];
         if(isset($tmp[1])){
           $html[$i]['inner']=encodeMe($tmp[1],$replaces);
         }
      }

         //Loop through that pair array, and build the new string
         $newString="";
         foreach($html as $h){
          if(!empty($h['tag'])){
            $newString.="<".$h['tag'].">";
          }
          if(!empty($h['inner'])){
             $newString.=$h['inner'];
          }
         }

        // VIOLA!
        echo $newString;


        // The string encoding function
        function encodeMe($str , $replaces){
         for( $i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++ ){
           if( isset($replaces[$str[$i]]) ){
            $str[$i] = $replaces[$str[$i]];
           }
         }
         return $str;
        }
```

Example here
[EXAMPLE HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18302b15409df0beb00373f3cd69ebca0a9fa132)

Comment: This removes all tags, and I can't seem to figure out how to put the tags back afterwards... since that's what I need to do after changing all the text.

Comment: I know, thats what I said in the answer.  I don't know how to do that either, but Im sure its possible, since you're looping through the nodes, you must have access to them somehow.  If I find that part out, I'll include it in this answer.  But just google DOMDocument and search around the documentation for it.  Im sure its in there somewhere

Comment: Possibly this will help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805207/how-can-i-get-an-elements-serialised-html-with-phps-domdocument

Comment: There you go.  I think I soved it for you. Albeit in a sorta hackish way.  But it will get the job done, provided you dont ever use the < or > character as a regular text string

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6c2a219e24e62a50ca201fa00164359a26c86f7f

Comment: I actually did something that will "hopefully" prove useful. Before I replace out all the letters, I replace all tags with numbers instead, plus \n since that was also being replaced, and then replaced them back afterwards. It just hurts my brain less. BUT, let me try that too... maybe it will also get me the result, but less work.

Comment: Either way :) ....you can copy my code straight off the sanbox if you wanna use it.  It works good.  Tested it with multiple bits of html

Comment: Wow, okay, yeah that is amazing.